# Control de errores al cargar dinámicamente las vistas con templateUrl y ngRoute de AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Así es cómo estoy cargando mis templates, al acceder a uno existente se muestra correctamente el template pero al acceder a uno no existente el navegador no responde y tengo que cerrar la pestaña, supongo que en ese caso debería de actuar `.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/error404' });` pero no lo hace y sucede el error ya dicho.

También quiero saber si creen que esta es una manera correcta de mostrar los templates, no me dará problemas a futuro ? Si tienen una mejor forma les agradecería que me mostraran cómo implementarlo.

```
.when('/news/:id',{
    templateUrl: function(stateParams){
      return '/html/news/' + stateParams.id + '.html';
    },
    controller: 'PruebaCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'prueba',
    title: 'Artículo'
 })
```

Comment: Para que pones un resolve en la ruta con un `$timeout`. Ese código tiene algun propósito? Porque cargas tus templates basandote en un id? La única razón que le veo a esto es que la estructura de tus vistas entre noticias sea radicalmente diferente lo cual me parece poco probable. Podrías mostrar como son los templates y un ejemplo de como son las noticias?

Comment: @devconcept Con templates me refiero a las vistas, es que no quiero estar colocando las vistas una por una en un ".when('/otravista',{})" y con este código quiero que las busque mediante el id que tengo en un ng-repeat que coge los datos de un json, funciona pero cuando abro una noticia que no existe o simplemente coloco una url que no existe, así por ejemplo "/news/noexiste" el navegador deja de funcionar y tengo que cerrar la pestaña. El resolve no tiene qué ver olvídalo. asta lo voy a borrar de la pregunta lol.

Comment: Hola @AdrianoJosué, quizás se esté produciendo un error de JavaScript, ¿podrías comprobarlo y añadirlo a la pregunta? Por cierto, estás usando el ´ui-router´ ¿no?

Comment: @rsciriano no, no estoy utilizando "ui-router" estoy utilizando el ngRouter normal de AngularJS. debería utilizarlo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podría hacer usar la propiedad `templateProvider` para implementar la carga dinámica de la plantilla porque tienes mas control de lo que está pasando.

El código quedaría algo así:

```
.when('/news/:id',{
    templateProvider: function(stateParams, $templateFactory){
    return $templateFactory.fromUrl('/html/news/' + stateParams.id + '.html')
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('Error al cargar la noticia ' + stateParams.id + ': ' + err);
            return '<h1>No se ha podido cargar la noticia</h1>';
        });
    },
    controller: 'PruebaCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'prueba',
    title: 'Artículo'
})
```

Como puedes ver se está usando el servicio `$templateFactory` de **ui-router** para cargar la plantilla. La llamada a este servicio devuelve un promise, que nos permite capturar el error para logearlo y devolver un HTML que se usaría como plantilla para mostrar el error al usuario

**Actualización:**

El código anterior solo funciona con **ui-router**, con **ngRoute** estamos más limitados y por lo tanto no se pueden hacer este tipo de cosas *(al menos yo no sé como)*

Pensando un poco más en lo que quieres conseguir y siguiendo un poco lo que comentaba [devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept) creo que se puede implementar de otra manera **más adecuada** y que consistiría en cargar el código HTML de las noticias desde el controlador.

El código que tendrías en el controlador sería:

```
app.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $sce) {

    $http.get('/html/news/' + $routeParams.id + '.html')
        .then(function(resp){
            $scope.newsContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
        }, function(err){
            console.log('Error al cargar la noticia ' $routeParams.id + ': ' + err);
            $scope.newsContent = '<h1>Se ha producido un error al cargar la noticia</h1>';            
        })     
})
```

La ruta la tendrías configurada así:

```
.when('/news/:id',{
    template: '<div class="containner">{{newsContent}}</div>',
    controller: 'NewsCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    title: 'Artículo'
})
```

Comment: ok te agradezco la ayuda, voy a implementarlo. una pregunta, cómo no utilizo ui-router tengo que cambiar algo del código de mi .config ?

Comment: Hola @AdrianoJosué la solución que puse solo funciona con **ui-router**, he actualizado la respuesta con lo que podría ser la solución basada en ngRoute. Espero que te sirba

Comment: De verdad te agradezco la ayuda, él código con el **ngRouter** no me funciono, pero investigue sobre **ui.router** y lo implemente en mi app y utilize el código que me enseñaste y funciono correctamente. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @AdrianoJosué de nada, me alegro que te haya servido. Yo uso ui-router porque permite hacer este tipo de cosas avanzadas y otras como la que se describe en este artículo en inglés [Creating Stateful Modals in AngularJS with Angular UI Router](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-stateful-modals-angularjs-angular-ui-router/). Saludos